# Charts.js rendering issue on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, charts, chart.js

I have a strange issue occurring with my Charts.js line chart.

Upon page load, nothing seems to be visible in the `<canvas>` element:
[image: Chart on page load]

However, once you resize the browser window, the chart displays as intended:
[image: Chart after browser window resize]

Has anyone else encountered this issue and know of a way to fix it?

The JavaScript for my chart is below. Please let me know if I need to alter it in any way to fix this issue.

```
function drawLineChart() {

var dates = [];
var clientCosts = [];

$.ajax({
    url: '../inc/wip-data.php',
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(item) {
        dates.push(item.date);
        clientCosts.push(item.clientCostsTotal);
    });
});

console.log(dates, clientCosts);

var chartData = {
    labels: dates,
    datasets: [{
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: clientCosts
    }]
};

// Get the context of the canvas element we want to select
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

// Instantiate a new chart
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    responsive: true,
    type: 'line',
    data: chartData,
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
}

drawLineChart();
```

[This issue is not replicating in JS Bin.](https://jsbin.com/vikanehaqo/1/edit?html,js,console,output) The only difference between the JS Bin and my local build is the AJAX call for the data, so that leads me to believe the AJAX call is what is causing the issue. Any guidance on what may be calling this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data used by the chart is not available when the chart is created. This is because the ajax call is asynch, and the data becomes available only when the ajax request is complete. 
In order to have the chart visible right away, you will need to use this call **myChart.update()**, in the "done" function of the ajax call after you populate the data, in order to update the chart:

```
...
data.forEach(function(item) {
    dates.push(item.date);
    clientCosts.push(item.clientCostsTotal);
});
myChart.update();
```

Comment: The script is now:     `$.ajax({
        url: '../inc/wip-data.php',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(item) {
            dates.push(item.date);
            clientCosts.push(item.clientCostsTotal);
            myChart.update();
        });
    });`

It works as intended.

Comment: Cool! Glad I could help!